# Advanced REST Client: adding query parameters

Tags: rest, client, query-string

Advanced REST Client seems like a neat REST client implementation to try REST-APIs. 
But, I can't find how I can add query parameters to the URI of the API, but without putting it up the with the URI itself.

for example, to generate some URL like
`https://api.example.com/v2/users/?age=25&fanOf=lakers`

i want to add parameters like `"age"=25` and `"fanOf"="lakers"`.

i know it's there somewhere but can't find it plainly on, otherwise intuitive interface, `Advanced REST client".

Comment: You should use, Postman FTW!

Comment: as i've used both, imo ARC has more flexibility than Postman ;)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

After a bit of failed exploration on Internet & SO of-course, got it from a tip of a co-worker.

The option opens up by clicking the down-arrow on the left-side of the url-box.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Screenshot with new version 12.1.4 of ARC client

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For version `17.0.9` -

1. Enter URL (with or without parameters included).
2. Click the pencil icon to the right of the URL input to edit parameters.

[image]

3. Then the menu appears

[image]